# How to solve a divergent linear system using iterative methods?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a matrix A which is symmetric and non-diagonal dominant. I tried to use Jacobi/Gauss-Seidel/SOR to solve it but it diverges. Is there any mechanism to condition the matrix for convergence using the same techniques?

Comment: You may want to ask this question at scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: For some reasons (which I don't really understand) some people attempt to precondition the matrix even for the use with classical iterative methods (instead of, e.g., Krylov subspace methods). These techniques are, however, generally useless and their theory is developed only for M-matrices.

Comment: Why not just use a better algorithm?  The ones you mention are never used in practice any more.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Never mind.